# scssでのコンパイルで Error: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: vscode, sass, scss

VSCodeでscssのコンパイル、style.scssを更新し、style.cssのファイルに書き出したいのですが、以下のメッセージが表示されます。
どうすれば解決できますでしょうか。

PCはmacです。

```
Error: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

ソース　DartJS Sass Compiler and Sass Watcher
```

Comment: 関連するコード等を質問に含めた方が回答が付きやすいと思います。質問は後からでも編集できるので追記してください。